# ASP MVC Refresh partial view grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to refresh a partial view grid after changing a record.
I have a button where the user can click on, than it will change a row in the grid. This works OK, however. I have to manually refresh the page to see the modification. Now I thought I could make a new JavaScript Ajax function to do this. So after the user push the button it will load the function `RefreshGrid`

JavaScript Function:

```
function RefreshGrid() {

    var numberPlate = $("#NumberPlate").val();

    if (numberPlate) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: appPath + '/Service/Grid',
            data: { numberPlate: numberPlate },
            success: function (response) {
                $("#Grid").html(response);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                $("#dialog .modal-body").html(msgErrorDuringRequest);
                $("#dialog #dialog-title").html(errorTitle);
                $("#dialog").modal("show");

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now the controller

```
public ActionResult Grid(string numberPlate)
        {
            IList<ServiceOrder> services = ServiceRepository.Services(numberPlate);
            return PartialView("_Grid", services);
        }
```

For some reason it is returning me the error function

```
error: function (response) {
                $("#dialog .modal-body").html(msgErrorDuringRequest);
                $("#dialog #dialog-title").html(errorTitle);
                $("#dialog").modal("show");

            }
```

But I have no idea where it goes wrong. Cant really imagine it is in the controller as I have a familiar function elsewhere which works flawless but perhaps I am missing something.
[image]

[image: Appears that it's going to the right controller]

Comment: Add error to question - it will help us to point you to the problem

Comment: could you try adding dataType: 'html' to your ajax call?

Comment: @iandayman what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @MiaSan $.ajax({
            type: 'get', **dataType: 'html',** url: appPath + '/Service/Grid', .... etc

Comment: @iandayman unfortunately it made no difference  :(

Comment: ok - if you can trace the http call and see what response you get back from the web call that would probably shed some light.

Comment: @iandayman I have a chrome plugin for trace. Posted img on question

Comment: You are returning a view _Grid?  That is the correct name right? I believe the "_" before means the view is private and not able to be requested directly, although returning it as a partial view is doing that, so maybe try removing the "_" before the name?

Comment: @BrianMains In the controller? I've already tried that as well, without luck:(

Comment: 500 internal error - so i guess your web service method ("Grid") is throwing an exception?

Comment: I got the exceptions handled but yes I guess so;)

Comment: 500 means there is an internal error so just run it with the debugger.

Comment: I dont understand, how you mean rean it with debugger? that is what I always do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try code:
Remove The All your jquery code ,just used below the code your RefreshGrid Function

```
var numberPlate = $("#NumberPlate").val();
 var url= '/Service/Grid?numberPlate='numberPlate;
 $("#Grid").load(url);
```

Comment: Not refreshing grid with this :(

Comment: what is apPath ?

Comment: you  remove appath

Comment: sorry i  missed /  pls add

Comment: run Your application

Comment: Does not refresh. However I got no errors. It just say the records are saved so it's on succes. however, it does not refresh the grid

Comment: and enter browser url path "http://localhost:63061/Service/Grid?numberPlate=BUR-722"

Comment: i think  this problem partial page

Comment: I found out it was indeed in the partial page. I voted and marked as answer! Thanks alot